# Regex for Alphanumeric with all special characters in US Keyboard

Tags: java, regex

Yet another question about regex.
Here is my requirement:

1. Should accept all alphabets.
2. Should have at least one Uppercase alphabet.
3. Should have at least 1 numeric.
4. Total length should be minimum 8.
5. Should accept all special characters in regular US keyboard layout only.

Below is what I came up with

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-=+/\\]`~!@#$%^&*()_+\\[;',.{}|:\\\"<>?])(?=^\\p{ASCII}*$)(?=\\S+$).{8,}$
```

But this doesn't work for `\\Admin123`

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**
Thanks @Pshemo .Just wondering, if there is any shorter way of doing this? Instead of including all the special characters in the regex itself.

Comment: Did you escape a backslash pattern? To match a ``\`` you need 4 backslashes in the string literal.

Comment: Why does it have to be regex?

Comment: `\\Admin123` will be entered from UI (password field)

Comment: What `[...\\\"...]` is supposed to represent? Should it accept two characters: ``\`` and `"` or only one: `"`? If it is the first case you need `[...\\\\\"...]` (four ``\`` to represent single ``\`` and `\"` to represent `"`).

Comment: Banging my head right now. Good catch.

Comment: Your regex can be refactored into more readable `final String regex = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\p{Punct})[\\p{ASCII}&&[\\S]]{8,}$";`

Comment: Tried that. Throwed exception. `Unknown character property name {ASCI‌​I} near index 60
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\p{Punct})[\p{ASCI‌​I}\&&[\S]]{8,}$` Near "&&"

Comment: I tried in Eclipse in main method.

Comment: @anubhava Not sure why, but your solution in comment has invisible characters at `ASCI[here]I` which are `\u8204` - Zero Width Non-Joiner and `\u8203` - Zero Width Space which was causing problems for OP.

Comment: Oh sorry about it.. I copy/pasted it from my STS (Eclipse) editor.

Comment: @anubhava: do you have a private nuclear power plant for Eclipse?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte lol :) No "nuclear power plant", it was Eclipse that comes with Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use more readable refactored regex as this:

```
final String re = 
             "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\p{Punct})[\\p{ASCII}&&[\\S]]{8,}$";
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/8Txu64)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.*[0-9])`: Lookahead to assert we have at least one digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])`: Lookahead to assert we have at least one lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`: Lookahead to assert we have at least one uppercase letter
- `(?=.*\\p{Punct})`: Lookahead to assert we have at least one punctuation character
- `[\\p{ASCII}&&[\\S]]{8,}`: Intersection composite character class to match 8 or more *ASCII* and *non-white-space* characters
- `$`: End

Comment: Yup, This works fine. Can you also let me know what all punctuation characters `{Punct}` holds?

Comment: That is one of the `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~` characters. See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!